Oracle Machine Learning (OML) df_datetime gives "no columns are selected" error
I'm having a bit of coding trouble if anyone can help! I'm trying to get the Datetime types from an oml.Dataframe df. I have tried this code:
 df = oml.sync(query=QUERY)
 df_datetime = df.select_types(include=['oml.Datetime'])

But I get an error that no columns are selected. Am I using this function incorrectly?
I found a workaround using
 df = oml.sync(query=QUERY)
 df_datetime = []
 for col, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
    if dtype.__name__ == 'Datetime':
       df_datetime.append(col)

and this does return Datetime objects, so I know they exist. I would much prefer using the select_types method if I can, if anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Is this Oracle R? If yes, please add the relevant tags

Removing the quotes around oml.Datetime will resolve the problem:
df_datetime = df.select_types(include=[oml.Datetime])

